# How to integrate existing Auth Service with kibana and opendistro for authenticating users

Tags: jwt, elasticsearch-opendistro

We have our own authentication server developed in NodeJs, which acts as identity provider for users. So We are looking for how we can integrate it with Kibana-opendistro.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

The security responsibility lies with the [security plugin](https://github.com/opensearch-project/security), so most of the configuration should be made there.

Opendistro Security provides support for a couple of authentication backends that you can refer here https://opensearch.org/docs/latest/security-plugin/configuration/configuration/. You can configure the security plugin based on the authentication mechanism used.

Alternatively, there is this concept of injected user where the authentication is completely handled by another service fronting the security plugin. Though I did not find documentation on this, you can refer to the code here https://github.com/opensearch-project/security/blob/565f47e804ec03aeeba02ca8def563b91307fcc7/src/test/java/org/opensearch/security/test/plugin/UserInjectorPlugin.java